# mysqli запрос не работает

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

вот мой файл database.php :

```
require_once("config.php");

class MySqlDatabase{
    private $connection;

    function __construct(){
        $this->open_connection();
    }
    public function open_connection(){
        $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER , DB_USER , DB_PASS , DB_NAME);
        if(!$connection){
            die("Database connection failed:" . mysqli_error($connection));
        }
    }
    public function query($sql){
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection , $sql);
        $this->confirm_query($result);
        return $result;
    }
   private function confirm_query($result){
        if(!$result){
            die("Database query failed: ");
        }
    }
}

$database = new MySqlDatabase();
$db =& $database;
```

а вот я пытаюсь проверить работоспособность и задаю запрос :

```
require_once("../includes/database.php");

if(isset ($database)) {echo"true";}else {echo "false";}

$sql ="INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, first_name, last_name)";
$sql .="VALUES (1,'olegsavchuk12','1111','Oleg','Savchuk')";
$result = $database->query($sql);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=1";
$result_set = $database->query($sql);
$found_user = mysqli_fetch_all($result_set);
echo $found_user['username'];
```

Но он не отрабатывает и выдает ошибку

```
"Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_gallery/includes/database.php on line 17
Database query failed:"
```

Подскажите как можно решить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема - вот в этом коде:

```
public function open_connection(){
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER , DB_USER , DB_PASS , DB_NAME);
    if(!$connection){
        die("Database connection failed:" . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
}
```

Вместо `$connection` всюду должно быть `$this->connection` - и все заработает.

Answer (score 2):

Этот класс просто ужасен. Им нельзя пользоваться. 
Не нужно писать своих классов, пока не научился пользоваться исходным API. Которое в данном случае не улучшается, а ухудшается. Код надо поменять на такой:

database.php

```
require_once("config.php");
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER , DB_USER , DB_PASS , DB_NAME);
```

код для проверки.

```
require_once("../includes/database.php");

$sql ="INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, first_name, last_name)";
$sql .="VALUES (1,'olegsavchuk12','1111','Oleg','Savchuk')";
$db->query($sql);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=1";
$res = $db->query($sql);
$found_user = $res->fetch_assoc();
echo $found_user['username'];
```